# INSERT INTO SELECT without duplicates MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, sql-insert, common-table-expression

So the thing is I have two CTEs from which I want to insert the values in a table.
In the P CTE I have 50 registrations, while in the M CTE I have 8. What I want is to insert in destination table all registrations from P **only once** and assign the registration from M randomly.

What I wrote insert 300 rows instead of 50. Here is my code:

```
;WITH P
AS
(
    SELECT [ID pacient]
    FROM Pacienti
    WHERE [ID pacient] NOT IN(SELECT [ID pacient] FROM [Pacient-Medic de familie])
    GROUP BY [ID Pacient]
),
M AS
(
    SELECT FunctiiMedici.[ID medic]
    FROM FunctiiMedici
    INNER JOIN Functii
    ON Functii.[ID functie]=FunctiiMedici.[ID functie]
    WHERE Functii.Denumire like 'Medic generalist'
    GROUP BY [ID Medic]
)

INSERT INTO [Pacient-Medic de familie]([ID medic], [ID pacient])
SELECT [ID Medic], [ID Pacient] FROM M, P
```

Comment: How come GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are used?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL related questions.

Comment: The semicolon is a statment **terminator**. Use them consistently and on every statement and you don't need the kludge of adding them as a "beginator" in front of WITH to accommodate the general laziness of developers.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities.

One: change the last query to something like

```
INSERT INTO [Pacient-Medic de familie]([ID medic], [ID pacient])
SELECT DISTINCT [ID Medic], [ID Pacient] FROM M, P
```

Or you could design a query that returns only the data you need and not a cross of all entries. The database structure is not clear enough to have a guide

Comment: I tried using DISTINCT, but it would give me an error: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Pacient-M__ID me__4CA06362". The conflict occurred in database "Clinica Medicala", table "dbo.Medici", column 'ID medic'.

Comment: Also , about the db structure, it is a db for a hospital, I have a table with patients (the P CTE), a table with doctors, one with functions(because there are multiple types of doctors) and a relational tabel FunctionDoctor that contains only the function ID and the doctor ID. I made the M CTE from these last three so I could have a table with only the IDs of the doctors that have a particular function. What I need is to insert into another relational tabel PacientDoctor all the patients' IDs without duplications and the doctors' IDs that resulted from the M CTE.

Comment: The scope of the destination table is that every patient has *only one* assignated doctor of the specific type I querried in the M CTE, while these doctors could be assignated to multiple patients. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Basically what I want inserted is (P1, M1), (P2, M2), (P3, M3), (P4, M1), (P5, M2), (P6, M3) and so on...

Comment: _every patient has only one assignated doctor_ But you cross join (intentionally or otherwise). That means your query will join every patient with every doctor - not just one doctor. And should we assume that you do NOT have the same number of doctors as you patients? Do you need to assign patients to doctors "evenly" such that each doctor has roughly "x" number of assigned patients and each patient will have one assigned doctor?

Comment: Yes indeed, I have 8 doctors and 50 patients. They do not need to be assignated evenly tho. Each patient should have only one doctor, but each doctor could have any number of patients. I am interested to know if there is a way in which I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO [Pacient-Medic de familie]([ID medic], [ID pacient])
SELECT [ID Medic], [ID Pacient] FROM M, P
```

This will produce a `cross join`, which is most likely what you're seeing. Try an explicit `JOIN` to reduce the results, something like :

```
INSERT INTO [Pacient-Medic de familie]([ID medic], [ID pacient])
SELECT     [ID Medic], [ID Pacient]
FROM       M
INNER JOIN P ON M.Key = P.Key
```

Your key is what should `JOIN` the two queries and reduce the resultset as your expecting it to